# How do I parse javascript code in Jint interpreter?

Tags: c#, jint

I want to make sure javascript code is valid syntax:

```
string test = " var i = 0; ";
Jint.Engine ScrptingEngine = new Jint.Engine();
bool result = ScrptingEngine.Parse(test);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `Execute()` method to "parse" your JavaScript and the `GetValue()` method to retrieve the value and then assert that it works as intended.

```
string test = " var i = 0; ";
Jint.Engine ScrptingEngine = new Jint.Engine();
var result = ScrptingEngine.Execute(test).GetValue("i");
Assert.AreEqual(0, result);
```

In addition, the `Execute` method will also throw a `JavaScriptException` if the JavaScript is invalid:

```
try
{
    ScrptingEngine.Execute("xx = ss == esfx = fuct()"); 
}
catch(JavaScriptException ex) {}
```

Comment: You are correct but Execute would actually run the code, I don't think that is a good idea.  I will still mark this answer as correct if it's not currently possible to validate code without running it.

Comment: @YongkeBillYu Validating JavaScript without actually running it is very tricky and takes a powerful AST parser.  I have no idea if jint supports this and I don't see a Validate method anywhere in the api.

Comment: Can you link me to the API?

Comment: @YongkeBillYu Sure thing.  All I could find was the limited README on GitHub.  https://github.com/sebastienros/jint

Comment: @YongkeBillYu looking at the source it clearly uses an ast, but I was unable to find a parse method.

Comment: Thanks, I'll use a different library.

Comment: [code]
var myscript = "javascript code here"

new Engine().Execute("var x = {" + myscript + "}");
[/code]

Answer (score 1):

If you add the script to a object it should not run any of the code.

```
var myscript = @"
var badFunction = function(){/* please don't run this*/ } 
badFunction ();"

new Engine().Execute("var noRun = {" + myscript + "}");
```

There is no guarantees though that the script itself doesn't break the object incapsulation.

Answer (score 1):

What about calling the JavaScriptParser?

```
Esprima.JavaScriptParser parser = new Esprima.JavaScriptParser(script);
parser.ParseScript();
```

When you add Jint to your project, you also get the Esprima namespace, and this is what Jint uses internally anyway (if I read the source correctly).

Then you can catch an `Esprima.ParserException`.